# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table dataentry has no column named mrsignedname (code 1): , in android

Tags: android

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TenDigiDataBase";
    private static final String DateEntry_Table = "dataentry";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CMOBILENUMBER = "cmobilenumber";
    public static final String KEY_CPLAN = "cplan";
    public static final String KEY_CFRUVALUE = "cfruvalue";
    public static final String KEY_DATACARDIMEINUMBER = "datacardimeinumber";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String KEY_CNAME = "cname";
    public static final String KEY_FATHERNAME = "cfathername";
    public static final String KEY_DATEOFBIRTH = "cdateofbirth";
    public static final String KEY_PROOFOFIDENTRYTYPE = "cproofofindentytype";
    public static final String KEY_OF_IDENTY_NUMBER = "cofidentynumber";
    public static final String KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESSTYPE = "kproofofadress";
    public static final String KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESsNUMBER = "kproofofadressnumber";
    public static final String KEY_C_SIGNED_NAME = "signesname";
    public static final String KEY_MRSIGNES_NAME = "mrsignedname";
    public static final String KEY_CSIGNES_POI_POA = "poipoaimage";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    byte[] byteImage2 = null;

    public DBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DateEntry_Table
                + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_CMOBILENUMBER + " text,"
                + KEY_CPLAN + " text, "
                + KEY_CFRUVALUE + " text, "
                + KEY_DATACARDIMEINUMBER + " text, "
                + KEY_AMOUNT + " text, "
                + KEY_CNAME + " text,  "
                + KEY_FATHERNAME + " text, "
                + KEY_DATEOFBIRTH + " text, "
                + KEY_PROOFOFIDENTRYTYPE + " text, "
                + KEY_OF_IDENTY_NUMBER + " text, "
                + KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESSTYPE + " text, "
                + KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESsNUMBER + " text, "
                + KEY_C_SIGNED_NAME + "BLOB,"
                + KEY_MRSIGNES_NAME + "BLOB,"
                + KEY_CSIGNES_POI_POA + "BLOB)");

        System.out.println("Database Createeeeeeeeeeeeeee");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DateEntry_Table);

        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void insertData(String id,
                           String cmobilenumber,
                           String cplan,
                           String cfruvalue,
                           String datacardimeinumber,
                           String amountpiad,
                           String cname,
                           String cfathername,
                           String cdateofbirth,
                           String cproofofindentytype,
                           String cofidentynumber,
                           String kproofofadress,
                           String proofodadressnumber
            , Bitmap signesname
            , Bitmap mrsignedname
            , Bitmap poipoaimage)

    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROWID, id);
        cv.put(KEY_CMOBILENUMBER, cmobilenumber);
        cv.put(KEY_CPLAN, cplan);
        cv.put(KEY_CFRUVALUE, cfruvalue);
        cv.put(KEY_DATACARDIMEINUMBER, datacardimeinumber);
        cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amountpiad);
        cv.put(KEY_CNAME, cname);
        cv.put(KEY_FATHERNAME, cfathername);
        cv.put(KEY_DATEOFBIRTH, cdateofbirth);
        cv.put(KEY_PROOFOFIDENTRYTYPE, cproofofindentytype);
        cv.put(KEY_OF_IDENTY_NUMBER, cofidentynumber);
        cv.put(KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESSTYPE, kproofofadress);
        cv.put(KEY_PROOF_OF_ADDRESsNUMBER, proofodadressnumber);
        cv.put(KEY_C_SIGNED_NAME, Utility.getBytes(signesname));
        cv.put(KEY_MRSIGNES_NAME, Utility.getBytes(mrsignedname));
        cv.put(KEY_CSIGNES_POI_POA, Utility.getBytes(poipoaimage));
           db.insertWithOnConflict(DateEntry_Table, KEY_ROWID, cv,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

    }
```

Exception:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table dataentry has no column named mrsignedname (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO dataentry(mrsignedname,kproofofadressnumber,cproofofindentytype,amount,cfathername,cmobilenumber,cdateofbirth,_id,cofidentynumber,datacardimeinumber,signesname,cfruvalue,kproofofadress,cname,cplan,poipoaimage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

When i try to insert data into table i am getting that exception which i post  but i dont know where am doing misting while i have uninstall then again install app then i try to insert data i dont know where am doing mistake please suggest me where am doing wrong  .

Comment: Mind the **spaces** on your last 3 fields. Uninstall your app, reinstall it.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi got it

Comment: which space you are talking about?